# Java- Get PDF from byte array from db and e-mail as attachment

Tags: java, pdf, jakarta-mail

Good day

I am trying to get the pdf content from a byte array field on the database and then e-mail it as attachment. At the moment, the file itself gets generated, but the attachment is blank.

When I do a part.getContent, the instance of the content is of type String and never of type ByteArrayInputStream. Please assist.

```
static MimeBodyPart readBodyPart(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException {
    MimeBodyPart part = null;

    final int sz = in.readInt();

    if (sz > 0) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[sz];
        in.readFully(buf);

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);

        try {
            part = new MimeBodyPart(bis);

            final Object content = part.getContent();

            if (content instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
                final DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource((ByteArrayInputStream)content, part.getContentType()));
                part.setDataHandler(dh);
            }
        }
        catch (javax.mail.MessagingException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
        finally {
            bis.close();
        }
    }

    return part;
}
```

Comment: Does the ObjectInputStream contain an entire MIME part, headers and body?  If you want to read the content of the part as a stream, use `part.getInputStream()` instead of `part.getContent()`.  And what's the purpose of the `part.setDataHandler` call in your code?  Why set the content of the part to be what it already is?